# Gstreamer video stream has very high latency

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I am trying to establish a video stream from my usb camera connected to a Raspberry Pi 3. I use a gstreamer pipeline but get a very high latency.

How do I improve my latency?

I have used the following pipeline to establish a video stream, it worked but the latency was around 5 seconds.
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.1 port=5600`
In order to improve latency I tried to reduce quality, bitrate, framerate and resolution however the issue persists. The pipeline I tried was the following.
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,fps=10/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=250 qp-min=22 qp-max=28 qp-step=4 key-int-max=5 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.2.1 port=5600 sync=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `tune=zerolatency` and it does the trick for me (200ms latency):

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! \
x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=250 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.1 port=5600
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. 
It definitely works a lot faster now. However there is still a perceivable 1 second delay. Do you have any other suggestions for reducing latency. If you don't thanks once again for your reply.

Comment: how are you playing it back? (on the udp receiver side I mean)

Comment: The raspberry pi is running a Raspbian based system called Ardusub. I am linking the documentation: https://www.ardusub.com/reference/companion/camera.html The gstreamer options for the reciever side is the following. 
!h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 !udpsink host=192.162.2.1 port=5600